# Accumulate all bad blocks and install OS in clean partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, bad-blocks

My WINDOWS7 been crashing a lot, with other problems like:

1. Running system hangs
2. Drives (partitions) disappear and come back on restart
3. System restarts without showing any error

Going through different posts somewhere I read to look at event viewer >> System >> disk error and it says bad block then it's time replace HDD.

Now I am also seeing that it only says

"The device, \Device\Harddisk0\DR0, has a bad block" there are many such errors but all says "DR0". So I wonder if possible I accumulate all such bad blocks in one drive and then install OS in remaining clean partition.

Is it possible?

OR

Also there is inbuilt Microsoft utility that check for bad blocks and repairs them [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors). So I could repair bad blocks and reinstall the OS on clean drive?

Other details about my PC:

1. I have 500 GB Sata Hard disk (four partition of approx 99 GB each, C:\ has WINDOWS7, installed few days ago due to problem discussed above, thought it would fix the problem). It is more than 5 years old HDD.
2. Dual Core processor
3. 4 GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Based on the age of the hard drive, you may be better off to invest in a replacement. Most modern hard drives can last anywhere between 3 and 10 years but typically start to fail after 5. There are utilities out there to aid in marking bad sectors(Spinrite6 as an example) but depending on the severity of the damage to the platters, it may only be a temporary solution to an aging hard drive.

Comment: please delete the answer, I want to delete this question as its already repeated. Thanks

Comment: Hey Paul, I tried to remove my answer text but it failed to save. Perhaps a moderator can remove the question block for you.

Comment: @paul there's no reason to delete the question just because it's a duplicate.  Leaving it actually helps future visitors find relevant info.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 you mean to say dont delete it but keep getting downvotes from future visitors right? very wise.

Do you really want answer same question twice? What is your name? Your name is? You Mr? Answer is same why keep all ??

Think before you write